# Dependency of Airflow Dags

Tags: airflow

I have 6 independent Airflow Dags out of which 2 dags are event based and trigger the dag externally using API (curl command) and rest 4 are scheduled for 'daily' .
I want to make a new dag which gets triggered on the successful run of above 6 dags.
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [external task sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html) to do that.